# Colors change on external monitor when I close laptop lid, Windows 10

Tags: display, colors, dell-inspiron, lid, profile

Help! I have an external Benq monitor attached to my [Dell laptop (Dell Inspiron 15 5567](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/inspiron-15-5567-laptop_service-manual_en-us.pdf)).  When I close the lid on the laptop, the colors change drastically on the monitor.  They aren't correct. The correct colors are when the lid is open.  Blues turn purple with it closed.  I am a photographer and I need the colors correct.  I had fixed this problem once before (years ago) but yesterday I installed an Dell update and now it's back and I can't remember how I fixed it.  I believe it had something to do with color profiles. I'm on Windows 10. Help!!

Comment: (Dell Inspiron 15 5000 series)

Comment: @K7AAY it's a 5567

Comment: Page 16 of https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/inspiron-15-5567-laptop_setup-guide_en-us.pdf shows you could be using either of two Intel (UHD Graphcs 610 or 620) plus two more AMD GPUs (Radeon R7 M440 or Radeon R7 M445). Please right-click on the Start/Windows icon and then choose Device Manager. Click the + for Display Adapters to expand it; what adapters are there? Right click on each; which driver versions do they use?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a problematic color profile:

1. From the Start menu, search for `Color Management`

[image]

2. Under the `Advanced` tab, change `Device profile` to `sRGB`.

[image]

**Update:**

It turns out the color profile was set to sRGB already.

**Plan B:**

Let's try *comparing* the color profile in use when the lid is open to when the it's closed.

1. Ensure the laptop lid is open
2. Open the `Color Management` applet and make a note of the color profile currently in use (i.e. the color profile in use when the problem does not occur)
3. Close the `Color Management` applet
4. Close the laptop lid
5. Open the `Color Management` applet once again and compare the color profile currently in use with the one observed in Step #2

   - If the same color profile is shown each time, the problem may be caused by something else.
   - If a *different* color profile appears in each situation, then change the color profile used when the laptop lid is closed to the same one that is in use when the lid is open.

Comment: Thanks, @wrecclesham.  Actually, the device color profile is already set to sRGB.  That was a good idea, though! :)

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. I'll update my answer with something else you can try, just to be 100% sure we've completely ruled out color profiles! 

Comment: Great idea. I did as you suggested and the color profiles are exactly the same whether it's open/closed (blue/purple).

Comment: Here is some more information that I have discovered...
If I go to "display settings" when the laptop lid is closed, it has no drop down under "multiple displays".  If I open the laptop lid, then under "multiple displays," I get a drop down that defaults to "duplicate these displays."  At that time, my screen resolution changes.

Comment: (continued)...  If I change this drop down to "Show only on 2", the screen resolution reverts to what it was when it was closed.  NOW, if I close the laptop lid at this point, the colors stay correct (blue looks blue).  All is good.  Cover is closed.  Colors are right.  But when I walk away, the laptop goes to sleep or turns off, I have to open the cover to turn it on and then when I close it again, it messes up again.  Ugh!  It's crazy!

Comment: Sounds like a driver issue for sure at this point! Updating the driver for your video card should fix this. https://www.dell.com/support/home/ca/en/cadhs1/products?app=drivers

Comment: Well, I am definitely stumping everyone!  I updated the video card driver and still no luck.  Same thing.  Perfect with laptop lid closed; blue goes purple with it open! :-(